# reading properties file failure

Tags: java, try-catch

I am having some trouble reading in a properties file. I want to read it in from console, but for now I am just using a variable to test it. I want to send the String of the file path to another class which will then read and set the properties, though I am getting a nullpointer and I am not sure why.

here is the `app.java` class with the main:

```
public static void main(final String [] args){
    String path = "C:/Users/aak7133/Desktop/test.properties";
    AppConfig config = new AppConfig();

    try{
        config.loadFile(path);
    }catch(NullPointerException | FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("fail..");
    }


}
```

and here is the `appConfig.java` class that receives the string (just the receiving part):

```
public void loadFile(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException{

    try{
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(filepath));            
    } catch(IOException e){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File '" + filepath + "' not found.");
    }

    setProperties();
    System.out.println(this.getFtpHost());
}
```

Just to see if I was reading in the properties correctly I did that print with one of the properties. The null pointer is in the main, so is it that I am not handling the try catch correctly or what?

Comment: post your nullpointer exception

Comment: okay, well rather the catch is just invoked. My console just gives off my "fail.." message before I added that tho all it said was nullpointer in main.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `prop` is not properly initialized in `AppConfig`. The `NullPointerException` may come from here.

Comment: @ the top of AppConfig i did `Properties prop = null`

Comment: wow.. ffs. That was stupid of me right after i typed it to you reading it outloud sounded dumb. changed it to `Properties prop = new properties();` and now it works :p thanks for making me double check!